# Some Imports Unresolved in JSP file Intellij

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, servlets, import

Am trying to build a web App in intellij using JavaEE. But i am getting unresolved dependencies in my jsp file even though that same import works fine in the servlet class. The project compiles fine with the import in the servlet class but when I try to use the same import in the jsp file i get errors.
I've checked my artifact library dependencies and the module is present in the artifact and everything is fine. Only that the import is unresolved only in the jsp file.

Here's a screenshot of my jsp file

[image: Here's a screenshot of my jsp file]

I can't figure out what's wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT :

to resolve the issue i had to select the classes and libraries i wanted to use in the jsp file as global libraries. So i did this by simply going to project structure > global libraries > new .... i selected the classes i wanted as global and then the jsp file recognized the classes. I edited the question In case anyone else ever runs into such a silly problem.

Thanks to all who tried to help.

Comment: Is it possible to share the project?

Comment: yeah thats okay but in what format exactly? its a big project folder.... or do you mean my dependencies and code? i could do that

Comment: Isn't it reproducible with some sample project?

Comment: after a while i developed a work around it.... it was something to do with my libraries or how added them. So to solve the issue, i had to go to project settings > global libraries > Add new..... and i selected the classes i wanted to be global, and the jsp file could now find it...... Sorry for the bother guys.